# Add row to specific column by header name/text

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

I have a column named "HeaderText_Name" and in this column, I want to add a row that has the text "Row" under that column.

I attempted to write some pseudo-code for it

```
databaseGridView.Rows["HeaderText_Name"].Add("Row");
```

If I do

```
databaseGridView.Rows.Add("Row");
```

It adds it to the first column no matter what. I also can't do something like

databaseGridView.Rows.Add("","","Row");

Then it adds blanks to the first two columns and I also don't know how which index the column is. So I would be more helpful if it was by Name or text.

Here is the actual code I have so far..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++) {
     databaseGridView.Rows.Add();
     databaseGridView.Rows[0].Cells[e.Node.Text].Value = completeInfoMatches[i].Groups[1].ToString();
}
```

Now, completeInfoMatches has more than 1 match because it's regex. How can I change the 0 to make it work?

**UPDATE**

```
int currentRowIndex = 0;
databaseGridView.Columns.Add(e.Node.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty), e.Node.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++) {
    databaseGridView.Rows.Add();
    databaseGridView.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[e.Node.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty)].Value = completeInfoMatches[i].Groups[1].ToString();
    currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1;
 }
```

I'm getting a lot of extra blank rows because of Row.Add

Comment: `Name` of  a `DataGridViewColumn` is different from `HeaderText` of it.  You can access a column by its name or by its index.

Comment: I updated the OP with a bit of help @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
foreach(int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++){
   var index = databaseGridView.Rows.Add();
   databaseGridView.Rows[index].Cells[e.Node.Text].Value = completeInfoMatches[i].Groups[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors about the first line, because the row I'm putting in may be the first one

Comment: Ok, I just added the first line, where you add the first row

Comment: Thanks! I have a bit of an issue tho so I updated the OP

Comment: Ok, so you are adding rows in the foreach right? So it won't be always at row zero..I will update to get the row index.. Take a look. Regarding the last part of your question, what do you mean by "How can I change the 0 to make it work?"

Comment: Okay awesome! I updated my OP to show how I did it. But now the `Rows.Add` is adding a lot of blank lines

Comment: Ok, I think thats because of the Rows.Add(), now I udpated to get the actual index

Comment: This is the issue I'm getting now http://i.imgur.com/p2cAtN1.png . They're not all on the same

Comment: what does completeInfoMatches look like? And e.Node.Text? what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Forlani ...

```
int currentRowIndex = 0;
int actualRowIndex = databaseGridView.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < completeInfoMatches.Count; i++) {
    var index = 0;
    if (actualRowIndex < completeInfoMatches.Count) {
         index = databaseGridView.Rows.Add();
    }
    databaseGridView.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[e.Node.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty)].Value = completeInfoMatches[i].Groups[1].ToString();
    currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1;
}
```